# String Pattern search and replace with new string pattern

Tags: c#-4.0

How to replace  all occurrence  string pattern except first occurrence in long text using  C sharp. Please help me with one example

Answer (score 0):

Giving an example. Please try to search for a solution on internet first. If no direct solution could be found, then please ask in this forum.

Not the exact code of C# but consider it as a pseudo code. There are many ways to do it.

> ```
> // First method
> int first_index_of = s.find(input_String);
> String temp = input_String.substr(first_index_of, input_String.length);
> temp = temp.replace("Old", "New");
> input_String = input_String.substring(0,first_index_of) + temp;
> ```

//Second Method

```
int i = 0;
while ( didn't reach end of string ){
 find next occurrence starting from index i

 // Ignore the first occurrence and Replace all other occurrences
 if ( Ctr >1) 
    replace the string

 // Exit if no more sub strings found
}
```

These are just pseudo codes. i expect you to do some work on it prior you use it.